# Facebook Parse SDK not working on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

I tried to convert my parse app into "universal app". I upgraded my project into Windows Phone 8.1 and I cannot install Parse SDK anymore. NuGet tells me:

Could not install package 'Parse 1.2.14'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Did anyone managed to install Parse for a project targeting Windows Phone 8.1?

BTW It worked for Windows 8.1 project.

Answer (score 0):

The nuget package hasn't been updated to work with the Universal apps. You can download the [.NET SDK from their website](https://parse.com/docs/downloads/) directly however and get the Universal app support. The SDK contains a Parse.dll, ParseWindows.dll and ParsePhone.dll.

You can place the Parse.dll and ParsePhone.dll in to your Windows Phone 8.1 Universal references and it should work.

Comment: now the projects compiles correctly but when ParseClient.Initialiaze method is executed, a System.IO.FileNotFoundException is raised in Parse.Phone.DLL

Comment: Unfortunately I am having this exact same problem. It only happens in the Phone project. I spent several hours browsing through their bug reports last night and my understanding is that this is a known issue and is currently being worked on. Unfortunately, it appears that they do not have any plans on migrating it over to the new libraries included with the Universal app. They're recommendation is to use the Rest API in the phone project, which is what I spent this morning implementing.

Comment: I opened another bug report on it [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/244432972417093/). I also noticed (after I had reported mine) that another bug had previously been reported [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1538205513073755/). Sadly however, it sounds like from this report, they might be dropping Universal support [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/327073484113608/)

Comment: Oh well...thank you very much for your time. So i will try to implement everything via REST API on my windows phone project. BTW - I create a windows 8 app (which also runs on 8.1 devices) and Parse runs just fine. If you don't need specific 8.1 features, this can be a simple solution.

Comment: The Parse library works fine for me under Windows 8.1, just not under Windows Phone.

Comment: Yeah sorry, me too...for windows 8.1 works fine, for windows phone 8.1 don't, so i migrate to a windows phone 8 app that works fine :)

Comment: Good to know thanks, I'll have to keep that in mind. Unfortunately I've already wrote a big chunk of my Rest service library so I'll probably just go ahead and target 8.1 with it.